# Does the 'scm' object in Jenkins pipeline scripts specify a single commit to check out, or a branch?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm working on a Jenkins pipeline which builds a project in parallel, on multiple nodes. On each node, source code needs to be checked out from a Git repository. When doing this via

```
checkout scm
```

as mentioned in the [SCM Step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/) documentation, is it safe to assume that every node will check out the exact same commit (i.e. is the commit to check out part of the `scm` object) or is it possible that - in case a commit is done while the build is running - some nodes will build a different state of the code than others (in case the `scm` object merely specifies the repository & branch to check out)?

I tried to see what information is available in the `scm` object, but it appears I cannot use the `dump()` method on it - the Jenkins pipeline plugin rejects this with the error message

> org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods dump java.lang.Object

Another attempt using `scm.properties.collect{it}.join('\n')` failed as well, generating a similar error:

> org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods getProperties java.lang.Object

I also had a quick look at the [`GitSCM.java`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/GitSCM.java) source code and it [appears](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/GitSCM.java#L1037) that the plugin supports checking out a specific commit - it's just not clear whether the `scm` object provides it.

Comment: In a related [blog article](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/226122247-How-to-Customize-Checkout-for-Pipeline-Multibranch-), it was pointed out that the `scm` object is sandboxed in case the pipeline script is read from the SCM (which is the case for me). I'll try to talk my administrator into disabling that for a moment, hoping that this will let me enumerate the properties of the object.

Comment: I just found [https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39968](JENKINS-39968) which seems to indicate that you can _not_ safely use Git checkouts in parallel. :-(

Comment: At least in multibranch and organization folders (like the [GitHub Branch Source plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/github-branch-source)) my experience has always been that a single revision is encoded into the `scm` object so multiple checkouts checkout the same tag/commit.

Answer (score 1):

If I am getting this right , what you can do is specify the git commit id for all the checkouts in the branch field like:

```java
checkout([
    $class: 'GitSCM',
    userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'path.to.your.git']],
    branches: [[name: '5062ac843f2b947733e6a3b105977056821bd352']],
    ...
])
```

where `5062ac843f2b947733e6a3b105977056821bd352` is the commit id of the commit you want to checkout on all nodes.

If you don't know the commit id. You can first checkout(a shallow checkout --- just the last commit) the master (or any other branch) and get the commit id ,store it in a variable and use it for all nodes.

E.g.

```
def commitId

.
.
.
get the commit id
.
.
.

node('first')
{
     checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', **branches: [[name: 
     **"${commitId}"**]]**, 
     doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], 
     gitTool: 'Default', submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 
     'path.to.your.git']]])
}
```